# App restarts as soon as spinner is clicked in android

Tags: android, web-services, spinner

I have used a .NET webservice to bind a spinner. As soon as I click spinner, the app crashes and starts from beginning. This is my code:

```
public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
    try
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,envelope);
        Object soap = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();    

        tables = new Table[((SoapObject) soap).getPropertyCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) ((SoapObject) soap).getProperty(i);
            Table t = new Table();
            t.Tableid = pii.getProperty(0).toString();
            t.Tablename = pii.getProperty(1).toString();

            tables[i] = t;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<Table> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Table>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, tables);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

}

Following is the error trace:

```
 06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at java.util.zip.Inflater.<init>(Inflater.java:82)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:182)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at com.example.mydemo.Secondactivity.addItemsOnSpinner2(Secondactivity.java:90)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at com.example.mydemo.Secondactivity.onCreate(Secondactivity.java:55)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-29 05:25:15.334: E/StrictMode(1037):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

Comment: In Java, you would need to to use AsyncTask. In .NET, it should be called Async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research i found out the solution.
Nothing was wrong with webservice call or code.Everything was fine but i have used the following code

```
     StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .detectDiskReads()
     .detectDiskWrites()
     .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
     .penaltyLog()
     .build());
     StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
     .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
     .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
     .penaltyLog()
     .penaltyDeath()
     .build());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondactivity);
```

What i did is just i comment the following line

```
     .penaltyDeath()
```